# Measuring delay caused by using a remote server from a different country

Tags: mysql, apache, networking, web-applications, delay

From logistic reasons I've stated using a database server that is physically located far from the main Apache server (not in the same farm, no internal network, not even in the same country).

I understand this isn't recommended, but as I said, logistic reasons.

The question is how can I measure how problematic is it really for my specific architecture? Is there a way to break down a query request to network time and actual process? Also, if you had to estimate, how much of a delay in loading pages would you think such a far database server should cause?

Comment: This isn't recommended? Who says?

Comment: @Strawberry I guess my server maintenance company, but isn't it obvious that using an internal network will make things faster than using a far away server? I'm just trying to measure how much slower it really is.

Comment: Perhaps it should be, but it's not obvious to me. Luckily, it's easy to test (sort of). I'm in the UK. Pinging my local server takes 11ms. Pinging google in California takes 33ms, so three times as long. But still not very long. To put that into context, human reaction time is 100ms. As long as you're not using loops to make endless round trips between servers, I'd be both surprised and interested if you'd notice much difference.